VS Code C# extension: "Project has unresolved dependencies" error in WPF project
I'm working on a WPF project in Visual Studio Code, targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2. I'm using csc.exe and msbuild.exe from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\. However, I'm encountering persistent errors in VS Code:

               


               

[Warn] [LanguageServerProjectSystem] Project c:\path\to\MyProject.csproj has unresolved dependencies
[Warn] [LanguageServerProjectSystem] Warning while loading c:\path\to\MyProject.csproj: Unknown build error, 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

To reproduce the error:

git clone https://github.com/MinimalWindowsDev/Industrial-WPF-HMI-Template
cd Industrial-WPF-HMI-Template
git checkout 0463c0b69dcc16cc56b0b766857d2f72e99ac014
code .

Interestingly, the project builds successfully when I run msbuild from the command line.
What I've tried:

Cleaned and rebuilt the project
Deleted bin and obj folders
Restarted OmniSharp
Updated the C# extension
Checked all references in the .csproj file

My questions:

What might be causing this discrepancy between VS Code and command-line builds?
How can I further diagnose this "unresolved dependencies" error?
Are there any known issues with the C# extension for WPF projects using .NET Framework (not .NET Core)?

Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated!
P.S. For those who end up here, it seems like I don't have this issue anymore. I am unsure what I did, but you may see the changes in this commit. Feel free to dig and try the changes one by one, and if you figure it out, please let me know in the comments or in an answer below.
